# not a function error when using function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code that i use to change the contents of a jsp page dynamically.But the code i giving a **not a function error** when using the javascript function.Event i tried to use the jquery expression but i am getting error for that to.i am including the script at the end to the body.
My code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("dom ready");


    $(document).on('click' , '#generatePdf' , function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var intervalId ;
        var statusText = document.getElementById("progresstext");
        var statusbar = document.getElementById("progressbar");

            $.ajax({
                url : 'ExportLogs' , 
                type : 'GET' ,
                success : function(response) {
                    alert("calling process");
                    trackprogress(response);
                } ,
                error : function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });

            function trackprogress(response) {

                $.ajax({
                    url : 'LogExportingStatus' , 
                    type : 'GET' ,
                    success : function(response) {

                        var val = parseInt(response);
                        alert(val) ; 

                        if( val < 15)
                        {
                            statusText.textContent("completed"); // I get the error here and also for all subsuquent textContent function call.
                        }
                        else if(val < 30)
                        {
                            statusText.textContent("completed");
                        }
                        else if(val < 60)
                        {
                            statusText.textContent("completed");
                        }
                        else if(val == 100)
                        {
                            clearTimeout(intervalId);
                            statusText.textContent("completed");

                        }
                        statusbar.style.width = val + "%" ; 
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }) ; 


                intervalId = setTimeout(trackprogress , 500 );
            }

            event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The error i am getting is

```
generatelist.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: statusText.textContent is not a function
    at Object.success (generatelist.js:55)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

I could not figure out what mistake i am making.Please any help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) really isn’t a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of **What is a documentation and wth could I use it for?**

Comment: @Xufox yes i understood the mistake.Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is not a function, but rather a property, the right code should be:

`statusText.textContent = "completed";`

Comment: please select it as the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) like,

```
statusText.innerText="completed";
```